# Requires GLIBC_2.14 while building Android App from Command Line in CentOS 6

Tags: android, linux, sdk, centos6, glibc

I am trying to build Android App from commandline using following command:

```
./gradlew assemble
```

But getting following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception while processing task java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
AAPT err(Facade for 725518148): /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0/lib64/libc++.so)
Thread(png-cruncher_6): Stream closed
```

It says **`GLIBC_2.14' not found**. I checked with command,

```
strings /lib/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC
```

So, its as expected, GLIBC_2.14 is not available in following list,

```
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.1.1
GLIBC_2.1.2
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBC_2.2.1
GLIBC_2.2.2
GLIBC_2.2.3
GLIBC_2.2.4
GLIBC_2.2.6
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.3.3
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.12
GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

So, I've tried to install GLIBC_2.14, but unable to install it on my Linux **CentOS 6**.

Some threads on Stackoverflow suggested to upgrade build-tools and platform version. I did that as well. Even reinstalled Android SDK, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can you please suggest steps to install **GLIBC_2.14** on **CentOS 6**?

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been resolved.

First I have manually installed GLIBC 2.14 by following steps given in this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176489/how-to-update-glibc-to-2-14-in-centos-6-5).

Still I was facing the issue. So, what I did was changed the Symbolic link of **/lib64/libc.so.6**. Made it point to **/opt/glibc-2.14/lib/libc.so.6**.

So, basically symbolic link is,

```
/lib64/libc.so.6 -> /opt/glibc-2.14/lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Note that this is likely going to break the system in unpredictable ways because you did not update the rest of glibc at the same time (which is also not recommended unless you have applied all the distribution patches).

Comment: This is work for me.make sure override the softlinks